# ksql-server refuses to boot up

Tags: java, apache-kafka, ksqldb

I am facing the following problem using Confluent Open Source platform, version 4.1.0:

```
[2018-05-01 03:43:33,433] ERROR Failed to initialize TopicClient: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. (io.confluent.ksql.util.KafkaTopicClient:257)
Exception in thread "main" io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlException: Could not fetch broker information. KSQL cannot initialize AdminClient.
        at io.confluent.ksql.util.KafkaTopicClientImpl.init(KafkaTopicClientImpl.java:258)
        at io.confluent.ksql.util.KafkaTopicClientImpl.<init>(KafkaTopicClientImpl.java:62)
        at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlRestApplication.buildApplication(KsqlRestApplication.java:237)
        at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain.createExecutable(KsqlServerMain.java:58)
        at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain.main(KsqlServerMain.java:39)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
```

Changing the listener port didn't help. How do we fix this?

EDIT1: I am starting the kafka brokers and ksql-server using

```
confluent start
```

Initially, "confluent status" shows that the ksql-server is UP, but the server goes down after the above timeout.

EDIT2: Yes, my kafka broker is running and here is my kafka server.properties:

```
broker.id=100
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:19090
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs-100
num.partitions=3
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
confluent.support.customer.id=anonymous
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

and ksql-server.properties:

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:19090
listeners=http://localhost:18088
ksql.server.ui.enabled=true
```

EDIT3: My suspicion is this has got something to do with incorrect bootstrap server url, but I am not able to find that yet.

EDIT4: KSQL server logs, as requested.

```
[2018-05-17 03:41:33,244] INFO KsqlRestConfig values: 
        metric.reporters = []
        ssl.client.auth = false
        ksql.server.install.dir = /home/<user name>/confluent/confluent-4.1.0
        response.mediatype.default = application/json
        authentication.realm = 
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = 
        authentication.method = NONE
        metrics.jmx.prefix = rest-utils
        request.logger.name = io.confluent.rest-utils.requests
        ssl.key.password = [hidden]
        ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
        authentication.roles = [*]
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = 
        compression.enable = false
        query.stream.disconnect.check = 1000
        ssl.protocol = TLS
        debug = false
        listeners = [http://localhost:18088]
        ssl.provider = 
        ssl.enabled.protocols = []
        shutdown.graceful.ms = 1000
        ssl.keystore.location = 
        response.mediatype.preferred = [application/json]
        ssl.cipher.suites = []
        authentication.skip.paths = []
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        access.control.allow.methods = 
        access.control.allow.origin = 
        ssl.truststore.location = 
        ksql.server.command.response.timeout.ms = 5000
        ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = 
        port = 8080
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        metrics.tag.map = {}
        ksql.server.ui.enabled = true
 (io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlRestConfig:179)
[2018-05-17 03:41:33,302] INFO KsqlConfig values: 
        ksql.persistent.prefix = query_
        ksql.schema.registry.url = http://localhost:8081
        ksql.service.id = default_
        ksql.sink.partitions = 4
        ksql.sink.replicas = 1
        ksql.sink.window.change.log.additional.retention = 1000000
        ksql.statestore.suffix = _ksql_statestore
        ksql.transient.prefix = transient_
 (io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlConfig:279)
[2018-05-17 03:43:33,433] ERROR Failed to initialize TopicClient: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. (io.confluent.ksql.util.KafkaTopicClient:257)
Exception in thread "main" io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlException: Could not fetch broker information. KSQL cannot initialize AdminClient.
        at io.confluent.ksql.util.KafkaTopicClientImpl.init(KafkaTopicClientImpl.java:258)
        at io.confluent.ksql.util.KafkaTopicClientImpl.<init>(KafkaTopicClientImpl.java:62)
        at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlRestApplication.buildApplication(KsqlRestApplication.java:237)
        at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain.createExecutable(KsqlServerMain.java:58)
        at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain.main(KsqlServerMain.java:39)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:258)
        at io.confluent.ksql.util.KafkaTopicClientImpl.init(KafkaTopicClientImpl.java:230)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
```

Comment: What command did you use to run ksql?

Comment: is your Kafka broker running? Can you share your `ksql-server.properties` config?

Comment: How did you confirm that the Kafka broker is indeed running?

Comment: Hi Michael, “confluent status” shows the kafka broker is up and running. My producers/ consumers are able to connect to the broker.

Comment: Hi Mahesh, are you still experiencing issues or have you resolved this?

If you're still having issues can you please post the full KSQL server logs of a startup attempt?

Comment: Still facing the above problem. Adding the ksql server logs in the last edit.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same exact problem on Confluent platform 5.4.1 and 5.3.1. I'm running MacOs 10.14.6. It turned out another application had taken port 8081 and therefore schema-registry was not able to bind it. I configured schema-registry to use port 8881 and reconfigured the schema-registry port on ksql-server configuration to that same value. This solved the problem

Therefore I would suggest you check that schema-registry is able to bind the configured port and that ksql-server is able to connect to that same port.